# Create two differently seeded independent RNG in C

Tags: c, random

How can I create two independent random number generators (without the necessity for being cryptographically secure) in C on 64bit Debian Linux, using gcc 7.2.0?
One of both RNGs should offer random numbers seed using `srand(time(NULL));`, while the other should be initialized using a commandline parameter for creating reproducible experiments.
Below example will seed the same RNG with two different values, how will this work having two different possible `rand()` calls?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    // seed first RNG
    srand(time(NULL));
    // seed second RNG
    srand(argv[1]);
    // use both RNGs in production code for 
    // different purposes ...
    return 0;
}
```

The purpose of this is, that I use one RNG for generating problem instances on the fly, which should be the same over all experiment runs, therefore following the same seed on all program restarts. The second RNG is used by the algorithm, which requires a (Pseudo) RNG differing on each program execution.

Comment: Also, what platform are you on?  Some platforms will support `drand48_r` and their ilk, which let you do this, but you can't do what you're asking simply with `rand` and `srand`

Comment: What are you trying to solve?  The numbers from any true random number generator are going to all be independent of each other anyway, so the actual number of random number generators shouldn't matter.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: For simulation and testing it may be that he wants one RNG that produces a different sequence of randoms everytime it is run and one the produces that same sequence every time it is run.

Comment: This is exactly the point. I tried to clarify this in my question above.

Comment: Create another thread. Each thread will use its own `rand()` state.

Comment: If you don't want to write your own I think @Joe has the most portable solution. [drand48](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/drand48.html) is not C standard but it is POSIX standard and widely available. Otherwise, depending on the quality of randoms you need it's not hard to write your own. rand/srand typically uses a simple [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) that takes only a few lines of C code.

Comment: I require a huge amount of random numbers, how is the performance of drand48? compared to rand()?

Comment: Like rand, drand48 should be blazing fast.

Comment: @JamesKPolk If a reproducible sequence is needed, that should be part of the question as it will likely affect any possible answer.

Comment: Use a special-purpose library, like, for example, my own ojrandlib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rand` is not a good tool for the task.

Since you are on a POSIX system, you should better look into the `drand48` family of functions. These have variants that allow you to specify the seed vector as function arguments, e.g `erand48`. With them you can just have two different seed vectors and call the function with the one to your liking.