# making random values in one function be same for each run while random values in another function be different for each run

Tags: c, random, random-seed, time.h

I searched the net and it showed the srand() method for generating new random values for each run , while i was using the simple rand() method for generating same random numbers in each run , but i want both these functionalities at different places in the program.
This is what i have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void first()
{ 
    printf("these random values should be same for every run\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        printf(" %d ", rand()%4);
    printf("\n");

} 
void second()
{ 
    srand(time(0));

    printf("these random values should be different for every run\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        printf(" %d ", rand()%4);
    printf("\n");
} 

int main(void)
{


    first();
    second();
    return 0;
}
```

please help.

Comment: What is your question or issue, the code seems to work for me

Comment: `srand` takes a seed value, hardcode it to some specific value in the first function and use the `time` function in the second function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create two differently seeded independent RNG in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171737/create-two-differently-seeded-independent-rng-in-c)

Comment: @Ôrel sorry i didn't check it properly

Comment: @Ôrel it is working as i wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

*new random values,* ... *same random numbers in each run*...

Use can use `srand()` in both, just use a `constant` seed in one:

```
void first(void)
{ 
    srand(3);//use constant argument for _same_ random values
    printf("these random values should be same for every run\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        printf(" %d ", rand()%4);
    printf("\n");

} 
void second(void)
{ 
    srand(time(0));//use variable argument for _new_ random values

    printf("these random values should be different for every run\n");
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
        printf(" %d ", rand()%4);
    printf("\n");
}
```